# Drush 10 is not working - seems unable to properly find the site

Tags: drush

Greetings to all of you.

Drush seems unable to properly find the site.

The output of vendor/drush/drush/drush status

```
PHP binary    : /usr/bin/php                                                   
PHP config    : /etc/php.ini                                                   
PHP OS        : Linux                                                          
Drush script  : /usr/share/site_dir/vendor/drush/drush/drush     
Drush version : 10.5.0                                                         
Drush temp    : /tmp                                                           
Drush configs : /usr/share/nginx/site_dir/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml 
Drupal root   : /usr/share/nginx/site_dir/web/web
```

Please notice that the reported Drupal root shows web/web

```
/usr/share/nginx/site_dir/web/web
```

In fact the Drupal root, seems to me, should be

```
/usr/share/nginx/site_dir/web
```

Any ideas, please.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'd do a search on the code base (specifically any scaffolding files) for the strings `'web'` and  `/web`, and see what you find. Maybe you need to remove it from some configuration file somewhere. Or it may be that you've misconfigured it in NGINX somewhere. Does the site load when you access the URL set in your NGINX config?

Comment: Also, what directory have you executed Drush from? And do you have Drupal Finder installed with composer in your project directory?

Comment: Does the site load when you access the URL set in your NGINX config?
Yes
What directory have you executed Drush from?
/usr/share/nginx/site_dir
Do you have Drupal Finder installed with composer in your project directory?
Can You be more specific, please.

Comment: Tanks @Jaypan. I found the problem: Somebody copied the file /usr/share/nginx/site_dir/composer.json to /usr/share/nginx/site_dir/web/composer.json

Answer (score 0):

This errors gets thrown when $alteredRoot and $root do not match during Preflight.
Often occurs with incorrect web-root settings in composer.json as can be seen here: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2023-08-09/drush-unavailable-after-drupal-upgrade-from-9510-to-1012

In my case there was an extra composer.json in /web (just like the original poster). Removing this resolved it for me.
But other solutions offered in the D.O topic might be helpful for some, so thought to share this.